# how to update a table value after click

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

lets think you have a table like this

MODELS.PY

```
class test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pluspoints = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    minuspoints = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_points = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

points.html

```
<form id="points_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                {{ form.pluspoints|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                {{ form.minuspoints|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="give the points" />
</form>
```

views.py

```
def points(request):
    points_filter = test.objects.filter(total_points=True)
    points_count = test.objects.count()
    
    context = {
        'points_filter':points_filter,
        'points_count':points_count,
        }
    
    return render(request, 'point/points.html', context)
```

now, I want to update the "total_points" -1 when I click on minuspoints and +1 when I click on pluspoints. Is this possible? or what could I do else.

Comment: Please show your views.py

Comment: I have added views but I'm really not sure about if its right.